# How to add web.config transformation different from Release and Debug

Tags: asp.net, web-config-transform

I want to add a web.config transform to be used in an automatic build/deploy cycle via MSBuild. However when I use Visual Studio to add the transformations I only get Debug and Release and have no option to choose the transforms. As far as I understand I need to add a new configuration profile but I really don't need it for anything else. Do I have to do this or there is some other way to use the transformations (especially with build tasks)?

I am also worried that if I add a new profile I may break code that checks for debug configurations:

```
#if DEBUG
```

Is this constant defined in the configuration profile somewhere or it is the profile itself?

Basically my question is how to add config transforms that are not debug/release for automatic builds?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg454290 -- Task 1 – Creating a Staging Configuration in Visual Studio 2010 Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Wow.  It's beyond me why this was closed as too broad.  The question describes the problem clearly and restates it succinctly at the end, and both it and the answers are useful.

Answer (score 3):

The [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg454290) in the other answer has lots of good details, but MS's notes on **finding Configuration Manager** were not useful. (at least for VS Express 2013)

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w.aspx) will help you open it. Once you get Configuration Manager open, creating new configurations is fairly straight forward.

> To open the Configuration Manager dialog box
>   •In Solution Explorer, open the shortcut menu for the solution and then choose Configuration Manager.

Edit
I later figured out why configuration manager was hiding. I had lost the "expert" setting in an upgrade. This setting is found under Tools/Settings.